# fatal error: 'llvm/IR/Module.h' file not found after Module.h is included

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm working on writing a LLVM Pass.

These are the header files that I included in the file.

```
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Constants.h>
#include <llvm/IR/CallSite.h>
#include <llvm/Analysis/LoopInfo.h>
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
#include <glog/logging.h>
```

These are the header files that I put in the include folder as follows:

> ```
> ── include
> │   ├── glog
> │   │   ├── logging.h
> │   │   ├── log_severity.h
> │   │   ├── platform.h
> │   │   └── vlog_is_on.h
> │   ├── llvm
> │   │   └── IR
> │   │       └── Module.h
> │   └── llvm-c
> │       ├── DataTypes.h
> │       ├── ExternC.h
> │       └── Types.h
> ```

The error that I keep getting is:

> 1:10: fatal error: 'llvm/IR/Module.h' file not found
> #include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.

Can anyone help me to see why this error pops up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler where to look for your project's `#include` files.

Add `-Iinclude` to your compiler command-line invocation.

I know this works with `g++`, and I'm pretty sure it works with clang as well.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to find more resources regarding `-Iinclude` but I wasn't able to, so I would like to follow this up to get more clarifications.

WIll adding `-Iinclude` automatically tell the compiler to look for all #include files, or do I still need to specify where to look for #include files after using `-Iinclude`? 
i.e. the command I'm using to compile the program is `clang $(llvm-config --cxxflags --libs --ldflags) -fPIC -shared myPass.cpp -o mypass.so` Where should I insert the `-Iinclude`?

Comment: Should I change it to `clang $(llvm-config --cxxflags --libs --ldflags) -fPIC -shared -Iinclude mypass.cpp -o mypass.so` or `clang $(llvm-config --cxxflags --libs --ldflags) -fPIC -shared -Iinclude "llvm/IR/Module.h" myPass.cpp -o mypass.so`

Comment: `-I` is a compiler command-line switch. In this case, `include` is the parameter for the switch. This tells the compiler to add the local `include` directory to the list of places to search for include files. Since you are specifying `llvm/IR/Module.h` in your `#include`, the compiler should find that path when it searches the `include` directory. Do not add the actual path of the include file itself to the compiler command line.

Comment: There is probably a flag to `llvm-config` to generate an include path

Comment: try `-I$(llvm-config –includedir)`